# How to connect to and remote database server

Tags: php, database, pdo

I have a project in which I need to store data in a remote database however I am unable to make to connect to the server. I am using PHPStorm in which I am clueless on how to connect so I tried on my local one where I am using Easy Php

```
<?php
$db=''; $user=''; $pass='';

try
{
    $conn = new PDO('https://dbadmin5.dnsserver.eu/;dbname='.$db.';charset=utf8',$user,'',array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    ///error in connection
    $conn = false;
    echo ' '.$e->getMessage();
}
```

This is my code, of course, I have filled the field in my case but I just keep showing errors

Comment: Your connection string is wrong. Please check [this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php). Also provide error messages if you want help.

Comment: You could add a tag for the dbms used. (However, this is not related to the SQL _language_.)